# Custom loss function: perform a model.predict on the data in y_pred

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metrics, loss, loss-function

I am training a network to denoise images, for this I am using the CIFAR10 dataset. I am trying to generate a custom loss function so that the loss is mse / classification_accuracy. 
Given that my network receives as input 32x32 (noisy) images and predicts 32x32 (denoised) images, I am assuming that y_pred and Y_true would be arrays of 32x32 images. Thus my custom loss functions looks like this:

```
def custom_loss():
    def joint_optimized_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        mse =  K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
        preds = classif_model.predict(y_pred)
        correctPreds = 0
        totPreds = 0
        for pred in preds:
            predictedClass = pred.index(max(pred))
            totPreds += 1
            if predictedClass == currentClass: 
                correctPreds += 1
        classifAccuracy = correctPreds / totPreds
        loss = mse / classifAccuracy
        return loss
    return joint_optimized_loss
myModel.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=custom_loss())
```

classif_model is a pre-trained model that classifies CIFAR10 images into one of the 10 classes. It receives an array of 32x32 images.

However when I run my code I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "myCode.py", line 94, in
>
> myModel.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=custom_loss())
>        File "/home/rvidalma/anaconda2/envs/tensorUpdated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 850, in compile
>
> sample_weight, mask)
>        File "/home/rvidalma/anaconda2/envs/tensorUpdated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 450, in weighted
>
> score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
>        File "myCode.py", line 57, in joint_optimized_loss
>
> preds = classif_model.predict(y_pred)
>        File "/home/rvidalma/anaconda2/envs/tensorUpdated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py",
>   line 913, in predict
>
> return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
>        File "/home/rvidalma/anaconda2/envs/tensorUpdated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1713, in predict
>
> verbose=verbose, steps=steps)
>        File "/home/rvidalma/anaconda2/envs/tensorUpdated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1260, in _predict_loop
>
> batches = _make_batches(num_samples, batch_size)
>        File "/home/rvidalma/anaconda2/envs/tensorUpdated/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 374, in _make_batches
>
> num_batches = int(np.ceil(size / float(batch_size)))
>   AttributeError: 'Dimension' object has no attribute 'ceil'

I think this has something to do with the fact that `y_true` and `y_pred` are both tensors that, before training, are empty thus `classif_model.predict` fails as it is expecting an array. However I am not sure on how to fix this...

I tried getting instead the value of `y_pred` using `K.get_value(y_pred)`, but that gives me the following error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape
>   [-1,32,32,3] has negative dimensions  [[Node: input_1 =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,32,32,3],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use accuracy as a loss function, as it is not differentiable. This is why upper bounds on accuracy like the cross-entropy are used instead.

Additionally, the way you implemented accuracy is also non-symbolic, you should have used only functions in `keras.backend` to implement a loss for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost same problem, and I tried this and it worked for me.

Instead of:

preds = classif_model.predict(y_pred)

try:

preds = classif_model(y_pred)

I am not sure about the reason but it is because when we use model.predict(y) it need batch_size and while compiling we don't have any, so we can not use model.predict(y).
Please correct me if this is wrong.